# fish shell, enter long command

Tags: command-line, fish

Given the usual size of the terminal window, short commands fit. Ex:

> stoqlt@desktop:~ > ls files

However, typing a command that is longer than the free space after the prompt, and reaching the end of the (first) line, the whole text entry changes to the next full line.

```
stoqlt@desktop:~ >
ls files1111* dirs2222* | grep 'stakcexchange' | sed -e 's/stakc/stack/'
```

This is really a nice feature, but I'd like to display the last two chars of the prompt (usually: '> ') at the beginning of this extra line, like

```
stoqlt@desktop:~
> ls files1111* dirs2222* | grep 'stakcexchange' | sed -e 's/stakc/stack/'
```

How could I create that feature?

Comment: Put a line feed in your prompt?

Comment: No. I use a singleline prompt. But reaching the right side of the window, fish transports my whole command entry to the next line, then I can continue typing there.